# Mutable borrow automatically changes to immutable?

Tags: rust

It seems that `u`, a mutable borrow, becomes automatically immutable in

```
let v = &*u;
```

Both `u` and `v` are then immutable borrowed references so they are both allowed.

```
use std::ascii::AsciiExt;

fn show(a: &str) {
    println!("a={}", a);
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = String::new();
    t.push('s');
    let u = &mut t;
    u.make_ascii_uppercase(); // u is really mutable here
    let v = &*u; // u became immutable to allow this?
    show(u); // both u and v are now accessible!
    show(v);
}
```

Outputs:

```
a=S
a=S
```

If I try to use `u` as a mutable borrow after

```
show(v);
```

compiler will recall that

```
let v = &*u;
```

is really not allowed:

```
cannot borrow `*u` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

Is it a bug or is there really some "automatically convert mutable borrow to immutable when mutability is no longer needed" principle? I am using Rust 1.13.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mutable reference *can* be borrowed immutably, however this is not what is happening here.

When forming a reference with `&`, you need to be explicit about mutability; unless you specify `&mut` it will be an immutable reference.

---

Your example can be reduced to:

```
use std::ascii::AsciiExt;

fn main() {
    let mut t = "s".to_string();
    let u = &mut t;
    u.make_ascii_uppercase();
    let v = &*u;

    let () = v;
}
```

The last line is a trick to get the compiler to tell us (in the error message) what the type of `v` is. It reports:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> <anon>:9:9
  |
9 |     let () = v;
  |         ^^ expected reference, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `&std::string::String`
  = note:    found type `()`
```

Here we have:

- `u`: an immutable binding, which is a mutable borrow of `t`
- `v`: an immutable binding, which is an immutable re-borrow of `t` through `u`

If, however, I change the `v` line to `let v = &mut *u;`, then I get `expected type '&mut std::string::String'` and then we have:

- `u`: an immutable binding, which is a mutable borrow of `t`
- `v`: an immutable binding, which is a mutable re-borrow of `t` through `u`

---

The important concept here is *re-borrowing*, which is what `&*u` and `&mut *u` are about. Re-borrowing allows forming a new reference from an existing reference:

- a re-borrow access the initially borrowed variable
- for the lifetime of the re-borrow, the reference from which it is formed is borrowed

The re-borrowing rules are relatively simple, they mirror the borrowing rules:

- if you start from an immutable reference:

  - you can re-borrow it only as an immutable reference, with multiple concurrent immutable re-borrow if you wish
- if you start from a mutable reference:

  - you can either re-borrow it as a mutable reference, exclusively
  - or you can re-borrow it as an immutable reference, with multiple concurrent immutable re-borrow if you wish

It is interesting to note that a re-borrowed reference can live longer than the reference it was formed from:

```
fn main() {
    let mut t = "s".to_string();

    let v;
    {
        let u = &mut t;
        v = &mut *u;
    }

    v.make_ascii_uppercase();
    show(v);
}
```

This is necessary to ensure that you can return a reference from functions; of course.

So, ultimately, a re-borrow is tracked down to the original borrowed value by the compiler; however, due the re-borrowing mechanics it allows forming an immutable reference to this original value even though a mutable reference is in scope... and simply make sure that this mutable reference is unusable for the lifetime of the new immutable reference.

---

When a function takes a reference, the compiler automatically introduces a re-borrow at the call site with the appropriate mutability; this is what happens with `show` here: `show(u)` really is `show(&*u)` with a new immutable reference formed for the duration of the function call.

Comment: I still does not understand. By calling _u.make_ascii_uppercase();_ I am sure that the borrow is mutable, or compiler would complain otherwise.

Comment: @RomanPolach: There are two different things here. (1) `u` borrows `t` mutably and (2) `make_ascii_uppercase` borrows the referee of `u` mutably. (1) lasts until the end of the function, however (2) only lasts for the duration of the function call (no return value to extend it). Then, in the lines `show(u)` you have (3) `show` borrowing the referee of `u` immutably for the duration of the function call.

Comment: So _u_ is muttable borrow before calling _make_ascii_uppercase_ and then it is an immutable borrow after that because it is _used_ as immutable? That is the thing I am curious about.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this either. Are you saying that `u`, despite being an `&mut` reference to `t`, doesn't actually borrow `t` until passed to a function which makes use of it?

Comment: @RomanPolach: `u` is an immutable binding, its value cannot change (it cannot refer to another variable), whose value is a mutable reference to `t`. The type of `u` does not change, it is *always* a mutable reference. However, one can borrow from `u` (forming a new reference), and this new reference may be either mutable or immutable.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: Uh... no. Or if I do, it's certainly accidental... Am I that unclear?

Comment: When I made `u` a mutable reference, then making another reference (`v`) should be disallowed. But the code compiles. That is I do not understand.

Comment: Moreover, if I add a new call to the end of `main` function that _uses_ `u` as mutable (like second call `u.make_ascii_uppercase();`), then the compiler recall that `let v = &*u;` is really illegal. But why it didn't complain before?

Comment: @RomanPolach: I reviewed the answer, to explain how I understand this. I must admit it's quite difficult for me as I find the behavior intuitive and never really attempted an in-depth explanation of how it worked, so please tell me if there are still portions of the answer that are unclear.

Comment: The section on re-borrowing makes it clear for me, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your reviewed answer makes me understand now. I was unaware of re-borrowing mechanism before, though I suspected something like that (but simpler) in transforming real `&mut str` parameter in place of formal `&str` function parameter. But The compiler cleverness making side-effect to `u` when binding `v` was beyond my imagination.

Answer (score 1):

This is confusing, so let's do some experiments.

Your code compiles:

```
let mut t = String::new();
t.push('s');
let u = &mut t;
u.make_ascii_uppercase(); // u is really mutable here
let v = &*u; // u became immutable to allow this?
show(u); // both u and v are now accessible!
show(v);
```

What happens if we change the `let v` line to:

```
let v = &t;
```

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `t` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
>
> --> :12:14

Ok, so that's different.  That tells me that `&*u`, despite being the same type as `&t`, is not the same; the former is (sub-)borrowing from *`u`*, but the latter is trying to reborrow `t`.

Let's try a different experiment.  Putting the previous line back, but now adding something new:

```
let v = &*u;   // the original reborrow
let w = u;     // Try to move out of `u`
```

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `t` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
>
> --> :12:14

Aha!  That confirms that `v` really is borrowing from `u` rather than directly from `t`.

Now, in the original, let's add an attempted mutation via `u` to the end:

```
let mut t = String::new();
t.push('s');
let u = &mut t;
u.make_ascii_uppercase(); // u is really mutable here
let v = &*u; // u became immutable to allow this?
show(u); // both u and v are now accessible!
show(v);
u.make_ascii_uppercase();
```

Now I get:

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*u` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

I think that basically explains what's going on:

- `u` borrows `t` mutably.  This stops `t` being accessed at all directly.
- `v` borrows `u` immutably.  This means that `u` can still be used immutably, but it can't be used mutably or moved out of.
- The other key thing is that you can only use mutable values if the *full path* to the item is mutable.  Since `u` can't be borrowed mutably while `v` exists, you can't use `*u` mutably either.  (This last bit is slightly handwavey; I'd welcome further clarifications...)

Comment: My take is that `u` is itself borrowed while `v` exists, and thus must obey the same rules as normal: if `v` is a mutable borrow, `u` cannot be re-borrowed at all, if `v` is an immutable borrow, then only other immutable borrows can be formed.

Comment: The most confusing is the side effect to `u` when binding `v`. In the first code example compiler check that `u` is not used mutably after `&*u` and allows taking mutable reference `v`. In the last code example it knows that `u` is really used as mutable reference, so it disallows `&*u`...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `u` is not mutable at any point, as it was declared with `let u`, not `let mut u`. The reason why you can mutate the `String` it points to is that it holds a mutable reference to it; `make_ascii_uppercase()` modifies `t`.

`v` is also immutable (no `mut` in `let v`), so when you call `show()` that works on immutable references, the borrowing rules are not violated - you can perform multiple immutable borrows at once.

Comment: Yes, by muttable and immutable I always mean the borrow/reference, not the variable binding. The problem I am trying to describe is that I made mutable borrow (u) and that borrow became an immutable borrow in some circumstances (when used only like a immutable borrow).