# Why does Rust allow mutation through a reference field using an immutable binding?

Tags: rust

If I have an immutable variable bound to a struct, Rust will generally not allow me to mutate the fields of the struct, or the fields of owned child structs.

However, if the field is a mutable reference, Rust **will** allow me to mutate the referred-to object despite my binding being immutable.

Why is this allowed? Is it not inconsistent with Rust's normal rules for immutability?

Rust **won't** let me do the same through an immutable reference, so an immutable reference has different behavior than an immutable binding.

Code Example:

```
struct Bar {
    val: i32,
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    val: i32,
    bar: Bar,
    val_ref: &'a mut i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;

    {
        let foo = Foo { 
            val: 6, 
            bar: Bar { val: 15 },
            val_ref: &mut x
        };

        // This is illegal because binding is immutable
        // foo.val = 7;

        // Also illegal to mutate child structures
        // foo.bar.val = 20;

        // This is fine though... Why?
        *foo.val_ref = 10;

        let foo_ref = &foo;

        // Also illegal to mutate through an immutable reference
        //*foo_ref.val_ref = 10;
    }

    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Comment: See also: [What's the difference between placing “mut” before a variable name and after the “:”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Indeed that article is similar - Although my question is more focused on why `*foo.val_ref = 10;` is acceptable, not why the other one's aren't. From my POV, it seems like none of the things in my example should be acceptable through an immutable binding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A short way to explain this is that mutability in *references* and mutability in *variables* are orthogonal to each other. The two forms of mutability are related in the sense that we can only mutable borrow something from a mutable variable (or binding). Other than that, each binary combination is possible in Rust:

```
               reference mutability
            -----------------------------
variable   |     x: &T  |      x: &mut T |
mutability |------------+----------------|
           | mut x: &T  |  mut x: &mut T |
            -----------------------------
```

We can think of many samples of code exemplifying what can be done with such a variable x. For instance, an immutable variable of a mutable reference can modify one other element, but not itself:

```
let mut a = 5;
let mut b = 3;
let x: &mut i32 = &mut a;

*x = 10; // ok

x = &mut b; // nope! [E0384]
*x = 6;
```

Even as a field in a struct, this does not conflict with Rust's safety guarantees. If a variable is immutably bound to a struct value, each of the fields will be immutable as well. In this example:

```
let mut x = 5;
let foo = Foo { 
    val: 6, 
    bar: Bar { val: 15 },
    val_ref: &mut x
};
*foo.val_ref = 10;
```

No mutations were applied to `foo` here: `foo.val_ref` still points to `x`. The former can be mutated because it's mutably borrowed.
**References are borrow-checked independently.** The lifetime parameter `'a` in `Foo` enables the compiler to keep track of the borrow.

That second example (shown below) does not work, because from a `&Foo`, we can only retrieve references to its fields (such as to `val_ref: &mut i32`). In turn, to prevent aliasing, a `&&mut i32` can only be coerced to `&i32`. One cannot borrow data mutably through an immutable reference.

```
let foo_ref = &foo;
*foo_ref.val_ref = 10; // error[E0389]
```

> Rust won't let me do the same through an immutable reference. So an immutable reference has different behavior than an immutable binding.

Exactly!

**See also:**

- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/155423)
- [How to mutably borrow reference from &&mut Foo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46688929/1233251)
- [Mutable borrow automatically changes to immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40654940/1233251)

Comment: [This is covered in the first edition of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/mutability.html), specifically: `y is an immutable binding to a mutable reference, which means that you can’t bind y to something else (y = &mut z), but you can mutate the thing that’s bound to y (*y = 5). A subtle distinction.`

Comment: Thanks! I am curious then about why my last example, `*foo_ref.val_ref = 10;`, is invalid though?

In that case, I have an immutable reference to a struct, and I'm using it to read a mutable reference to a different object. Why is that not okay if the other situation with the immutable binding is? Either way I'm not modifying the data of the immutable structure.

Comment: (I guess my overall confusion is that it seems inconsistent - It seems like mutability is transitive in some cases and not in others)

Comment: @something_clever Indeed, mutability is, in a way, inherited through a reference: from `&Foo` we can only retrieve immutable references to its fields, and a `&&mut T` becomes a `&&T`. I can update the answer with this concern tomorrow.

Comment: @E_net4 So I wonder why the decision was made for mutability to **not** be inherited through bindings. In my example, my feeling is actually that Rust shouldn't accept any of them.

That is - If my binding is immutable I shouldn't be able to transitively mutate references, even if I have them borrowed mutably.

Comment: @E_net4 Sorry to keep peppering you with questions, but you're helping me understand a lot better :)

Something I also find kind of weird though is that the immutability **is** transitive to the non-reference members of the struct, even recursively (I can't modify a field-of-a-field-of-a-field of my immutable binding). And that doesn't involve re-targeting the immutable variable...

Comment: @something_clever I have updated the answer with those concerns.

Comment: Thank you. Again follow-up question though - I see now why it's technically 'safe' to retrieve a mutable reference from an immutable binding, but is it 'correct' to allow it?

Because it's technically 'safe' as well for me to mutate an i32 through an immutable binding, since I have exclusive ownership and I'm not re-targeting the binding. The reason we even have immutable bindings is for semantics, not safety.

Comment: @something_clever That is indeed use case dependant and potentially opinion based. Users with a functional programming background, for instance, might prefer moving content from one immutable binding to another instead of mutating a value in a single variable. Rust allows both, but leaves those decisions to the programmer.