# Rust method that accepts and treats any kind of string as immutable and produces a new immutable string?

Tags: string, rust, arguments, traits

I'm new to Rust. I want to write a method (trait implementation?) that takes any of a String or a string slice, treats it as immutable, and returns a new immutable string. Let's say `foo` is a method that doubled whatever input you give it:

```
let x = "abc".foo(); // => "abcabc"
let y = x.foo(); // => "abcabcabcabc"
let z = "def".to_string().foo(); // => "defdef"
```

In this case, I do not care about safety or performance, I just want my code to compile for a throwaway test. If the heap grows infinitely, so be it. If this requires two trait implementations, that's fine.

Comment: Do you want to have a `String` or `&str` in the end?

Comment: Whichever, as long as I can pass it back into the same function without re-casting.

Comment: In Rust we don't use the term casting. Also, *"pass it back into the same function"*: are you speaking about recursion?

Comment: It is not very clear for me, what you want. Do you want to accept a string slice, e.g. something you can read chars of but not modify it or do you want a `String` which you can modify,e.g. replace, append, prepend, ... chars. It's a huge difference.

Comment: `let x = foo("abc"); foo(x);`

Comment: Then accept a string slice and return it `fn foo(s: &str) -> &str`. Call it with `foo("ABC")` or `foo(&String::from("ABC"))`

Comment: Example: (doesn't compile) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=a6b420adc6efd0f13701621b8a098de5 (will update Q when I understand)

Comment: Of course that doesn't work, because rust doesn't support operater overloading

Comment: @hellow, yeah I'm showing you what I'm trying to get at. If I had the solution, I'd post an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184390/discussion-between-hellow-and-petrus-theron).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between Rust's \`String\` and \`str\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=ad8b6acfe245fdde50ff623edffb8356

Comment: It will depend on the kind of trait. Without more information, we can only tell you to make two `impl` blocks. If you don't know how to implement traits yet, [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html) is your friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-or)

Comment: Updated my question. @E_net4iskindandwelcoming two traits is fine. I just want to reclaim usability, even at the cost of safety/perf. (in this case).

Comment: Two traits does not make sense here, since you can have just one for the intended behaviour (with multiple implementations). Note that immutability does not come to play when returning values from a function. More on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/1233251) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50124680/1233251).

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming, thanks, but you suggested using two traits above. I don't really care about what the solution entails or Rust's design philosophy, I just want my code to compile and not care about strings or slices until a future version of the borrow checker can "do the right thing" and warn me about potential heap problems. I'm just trying to get productive because I have a job to do, knowingly at the cost of doing "the wrong thing".

Comment: Actually, I said two `impl` blocks, which makes two implementations rather than two traits. I can indeed answer the question, but you are _strongly_ advised to re-read the book on making and implementing traits.

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming my mistake on "two traits", I should have said "two trait impls".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say `foo` is a method that doubled whatever input you give it.

A [trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html) is a perfectly good way to do this, since it makes one common behavior:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> String;
}
```

... applied to multiple types:

```
impl Foo for String {
    fn foo(&self) -> String {
        let mut out = self.clone();
        out += self;
        out
    }
}

impl<'a> Foo for &'a str {
    fn foo(&self) -> String {
        let mut out = self.to_string();
        out += self;
        out
    }
}
```

Using:

```
let x = "abc".foo();
assert_eq!(&x, "abcabc");
let z = "shep".to_string().foo();
assert_eq!(&z, "shepshep");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=efcd3c3008336b0b8d3bfedd7f969f7f)

The output is an owned string. Whether this value immutable or not, as typical in Rust, only comes at play at the calling site.

See also:

- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/1233251)

Comment: Fantastic! Is there a way to return the String as immutable? The knowledge I was missing was how to write the lifetimes like, `impl<'a> Foo for &'a str`. Obviously I have *not* read the book on traits :).

Comment: Having the `String` immutable is imposed by the caller of the function instead, by keeping it in an immutable binding. The links I posted above should help you clear this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a borrowed string `&str` at the end:

```
trait Foo {
    fn display(&self);
}

impl<T> Foo for T where T: AsRef<str> {
    fn display(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.as_ref());
    }
}

fn main() {
    "hello".display();
    String::from("world").display();
}
```

If you want an owned `String`:

```
trait Foo {
    fn display(self);
}

impl<T> Foo for T where T: Into<String> {
    fn display(self) {
        let s: String = self.into();
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}

fn main() {
    "hello".display();
    String::from("world").display();
}
```

Comment: I tried AsRef, but I got something about `T` cannot be safely shared between threads when using the result of `display()` when it has return value, i.e. `let x ="abc".display()`. Will try to provide code to replicate.

Comment: @PetrusTheron This has nothing to do with your question. That's an issue about multithreading code.

Comment: your example but returning a &str: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3fa379e099e74245ab6efe5fe497b499 . I had to add a lifetime, but I can't get it to compile. Can you help me tweak it? Assume my machine has infinite memory.

Comment: @PetrusTheron You should read more about Rust strings: `&str` vs `String`. You can find a lot of useful links, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str