# what is the difference between these lines in RUST?

Tags: rust, ownership

what is the difference between these two scenario I have the same functionality with 2 different model and it is a bit confusing for me !

```
//model_1

let mut my_str = String::from("ali");
let str1 = &mut my_str; // defining str1 without "mut"

//model_2

let mut my_str = String::from("ali");
let mut str1 = &mut my_str // defining str1 with "mut"
```

Comment: This looks like it might be a duplicate of [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587698/whats-the-difference-between-placing-mut-before-a-variable-name-and-after-the) Do the answers to that question answer your own?

Comment: Also see [Why does Rust allow mutation through a reference field using an immutable binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124680/why-does-rust-allow-mutation-through-a-reference-field-using-an-immutable-bindin) which is not about your question specifically, but might help you understand the dual meaning of `mut` better.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the similarity: neither of them compiles, because you cannot acquire a mutable reference (`&mut`) of an object that is itself not defined as `mut`.

As for the **correct** version, it is the following:

```
let mut my_str = String::from("ali");
let str2 = &mut my_str;
```

`my_str` needs to be defined as mutable if we are to grab a mutable reference to it, so that makes the first line unambiguous.

On the second line, the `mut` prefix to `str2` is only necessary if you are going to modify what reference `str2` points to. As long as you are only modifying the content of the string (without changing what string you are modifying) you do not need it.

Comment: yeah it is true, it was my fault I have corrected that in my question

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Correct. Not entirely sure what I was thinking but it definitely wasn't the right thing.